# 2 gb vs 4 gb on the AMD/Sapphire R7 240 card, will it make a difference for movies, esp bluray?

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card

W7 64 bit 4 GB Ram, i5 750@2.67 GHz. I watch a lot of movies (bluray) and need a better card. The other specs on these cards are identical except the RAM, Processor 730 MHz, Memory Speed 900 MHz. The price difference is about $15, which is not an issue, but I don't want to spend money on something that won't make any difference.

Will getting a 2gb card vs a 4gb card make a difference for watching movies?

Comment: The differance in RAM is negligible for your usecase as described. All else being equal, go with the cheaper.  Also, if you are having difficulties with video playback, focus on Codecs and support for hardware accelleration.

Comment: I have no idea what your question is.

Answer (score 1):

For watching blu-Ray movies this difference in VRAM will make no difference

Answer (score 0):

You don't need 4GB VRAM to watch blu-ray disks perfectly, 2GB VRAM is perfectly fine. VRAM is used more in games. So the 2GB VRAM is fine, but i don't think you need one since old cards will also be good enough. GPU does affect watching videos since there's video players that use hardware acceleration.

The CPU is also important, i think it does all the loading of frames. But since you have an Intel i5 750, it shouldn't be the problem.

Software (video players in this case) is something that you have to keep in mind. These are video players i recommend:

[**Media Player Classic (MPC)**](https://mpc-hc.org/)

[**VLC Media Player**](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html)

So, your graphics card should be fine if your getting it (get AMD Radeon R7 240 2GB VRAM, not 4GB VRAM it's not needed). Your CPU (Intel i5 750) is also fine). Oh, the RAM is no problem. And your video player is up to you.

I think this helped you, warn me if you to now something, GL!